# min() arg is an empty sequence #error - min() arg is an empty sequence ..for the following code-

Tags: google-colaboratory, bioinformatics

i am trying to plot for dataframe bioactivity class using seaborn.

`plt.figure(figsize=(5.5, 5.5))`

`sns.countplot(x='bioactivity_class',data=df_2class,edgecolor='black')`

`plt.xlabel('Bioactivity class',fontsize=14,fontweight='bold')`

`plt.ylabel('Frequency',fontsize=14,fontweight='bold')`

`plt.savefig('plot_bioactivity_class.pdf')`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.